# Simple inheritance -- strange compiler error

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have this simple piece of code that wraps `struct timespec` and adds static members for its minimum and maximum.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits>
struct Timespec : public timespec {
    Timespec() :timespec() {};
    Timespec(decltype(tv_sec) s, 
                     decltype(tv_nsec) ns
            ) {
        tv_sec = s;
        tv_nsec = ns;
    }
    static const Timespec max;
    static const Timespec min;
};

const Timespec Timespec::min  = Timespec(0,0);
const Timespec Timespec::max  = Timespec(
        std::numeric_limits<decltype((timespec().tv_sec))>::max(), 
        std::numeric_limits<decltype((timespec().tv_nsec))>::max()
    );
```

It compiles OK, but if I replace `decltype((timespec()/*...*/` with
 `decltype((Timespec()/*...*/` in the two lines at the end, I get:

```
$ make timespec.o
g++ -std=c++0x   -c -o timespec.o timespec.cc
In file included from timespec.cc:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/limits: In instantiation of ‘static constexpr _Tp std::numeric_limits<_Tp>::max() [with _Tp = long int&]’:
timespec.cc:18:55:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/limits:313:48: error: value-initialization of reference type ‘long int&’
       max() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return _Tp(); }
                                                ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/limits:313:51: error: body of constexpr function ‘static constexpr _Tp std::numeric_limits<_Tp>::max() [with _Tp = long int&]’ not a return-statement
       max() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return _Tp(); }
                                               ^
```

Should it be doing this?

Comment: Please show the actual code that has the error.

Comment: You may wish to use `std::remove_reference_t` .

Comment: Drop the extra parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decltype(unparenthesized class member access)` returns the declared type of the entity referenced.

`decltype((class member access))` returns something different. If the type of the class member access expression is `T`, then the returned type is `T&` if the expression is an lvalue, `T&&` if the expression is an xvalue, and `T` if the expression is a prvalue.

Before [CWG 616](http://wg21.link/cwg616), if `E2` names a non-static data member of non-reference type, then `E1.E2` has the same value category as `E1`. So given `struct A { double x; };`, `decltype(A().x)` and `decltype((A().x))` are both `double` (`A()` is a prvalue).

After CWG 616, `E1.E2` is now an lvalue if `E1` is an lvalue, and an xvalue otherwise (again, when `E2` names a non-static data member of non-reference type). So `decltype(A().x)` should be `double` and `decltype((A().x))` should be `double &&`.

Since CWG 616 is a defect report, it applies retroactively; your original code should not compile in a conforming compiler.

The actual behavior you observe appears to be a compiler bug. Even if it doesn't implement CWG 616's resolution, there is nothing in any revision of the standard that allows it to differentiate between `timespec().tv_nsec` and `Timespec().tv_nsec`, or to make `decltype((timespec().tv_nsec))` return an lvalue reference.

Comment: Reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67633. Clang's behavior here is at least consistent, and suggests that they simply haven't yet implemented CWG 616's resolution.

Comment: Correct, clang [doesn't implement CWG616](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html#616) yet